# How can I count method calls inside APK? (using .smali format)

Tags: java, android, apk, smali, apktool

I am trying to develop a tool that basically analyses an Android app APK and counts the number of calls to a specific API method (e.g., `android.app.AlarmManager.set()`)

**1. What approach do you recommend?**

So far I have used [APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool) and now I have`.smali` files.
However, for the same java source, I can have multiple files:

- `ExportAsyncTask$1.smali`
- `ExportAsyncTask$2.smali`
- `ExportAsyncTask$3.smali`
- `ExportAsyncTask$4.smali`

**2. What do these multiple files mean?**

**3. The resulting `.smali` files also include external libraries that I would like to leave out the analysis. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What approach do you recommend?**

Yes, Apktool can be used for your task. Each `java` class in the APK will be represented by a `.smali` file in directories tree representing the packages. Smali - is the Android Virtual Machine language. The language is much simpler than Java and hence easier for analysis. In your case you should search for `invoke` opcodes and `Landroid/app/AlarmManager;->set` strings. If you are working in Linux, you can for example `grep` and count them. In Windows you have text editors like Notepad++ that allow text search in multiple files.

**2. What do these multiple files mean?**

In Java there are internal classes and implicit internal classes. The former will appear in `OutherClass$InnerClass.smali` and the later, having no name of its own, get numbers, like `OuterClass$1.smali`. You sometimes even get more deep levels like `a$b$c$1.smali`.

**3. The resulting .smali files also include external libraries that I would like to leave out the analysis. How can I do that?**

You have no precise way to do that. But generally speaking, when you look at the packages/directory tree of many samples you usually grasp the pattern. E.g. usually application code is in `com.*` package and `android.*`, `org.*` and `uk.*` include libraries. After such inspection you simply exclude those directories from your search.